# What is this Maven error ? "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration...)"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pentaho

*"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.soebes.maven.plugins:iterator-maven-plugin:  0.4:iterator (execution: javascript-dependencies_unpack-dependencies, phase: initialize)"*

Trying to build Pentaho projects at https://github.com/pentaho. None of them will build except maven-parent-poms at https://github.com/pentaho/maven-parent-poms. Almost every other project throws this error in the corresponding .pom file. Refer to the screen snip, below, for the location of the error.

I did override the Eclipse Maven extension with the current version of Maven from Apache. Didn't change anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
    <artifactId>pentaho-platform-ce-parent</artifactId>
    <version>8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>pentaho-platform-api</artifactId>
  <version>8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.reuseForks>false</maven-surefire-plugin.reuseForks>
    <mockito-all.version>1.8.5</mockito-all.version>
    <license.header.definition.file>${basedir}/../license/styles/javadoc_style_license_header.xml</license.header.definition.file>
    <commons-lang.version>2.4</commons-lang.version>
    <license.header.file>${basedir}/../license/templates/LGPL-2.1.txt</license.header.file>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>${dom4j.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
      <artifactId>pentaho-connections</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
      <artifactId>pentaho-actionsequence-dom</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
      <artifactId>pentaho-xul-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
      <artifactId>pentaho-database-model</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
      <artifactId>pentaho-service-coordinator</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>${mockito-all.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mycila</groupId>
        <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: try to add `<pluginManagement> ` tag around your `<plugins>` tag see if that works

Comment: Does it run when you do ``mvn package`` using the command line?

Comment: @UlugToprak changing the pom isn't the right approach. The projects are from github and as such, we should assume they are correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is related to [Eclipse M2E](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html) where you need to tell Eclipse that it should for example ignore the plugin etc.

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
     <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
     <configuration>
       <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
         <pluginExecutions>
           <pluginExecution>
             <pluginExecutionFilter>
               <groupId>some-group-id</groupId>
               <artifactId>some-artifact-id</artifactId>
               <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
               <goals>
                 <goal>some-goal</goal>
               </goals>
             </pluginExecutionFilter>
             <action>
               <ignore/>
             </action>
           </pluginExecution>
         </pluginExecutions>
       </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

This is the old way of doing this. There is newer way [since 1.7 of m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-17.html):

You can include the ignore etc. directly into the configuration of the execution:

```
<?m2e ignore?> 
<?m2e execute?>
<?m2e execute onConfiguration?> 
<?m2e execute onIncremental?> 
<?m2e execute onConfiguration,onIncremental?> 
<?m2e configurator configuratorId?>
```

For example:

```xml
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <?m2e ignore?>
            <id>flatten</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>flatten</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <?m2e ignore?>
            <id>flatten.clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: That is the entire pom. I posted it in the OP.